# jquery fancybox iframe box position to section

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox, anchor

I'd like to setup a jquery iframe box, prefer [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) but any will do. Though what I need help with is positioning the html page inside of the iframe. I'd like it to go to an anchor, then move the page over to the right because I don't need to show the navbar... just the content. The anchor is probably easy just iframepage.html#anchorID ... though how would I position the content inside the iframe to move right?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a negative margin or padding property during the initialization of fancybox?